# Android Studio-manifest merger failed

Tags: android, android-studio-2.2

I am getting the below error message.

> **Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
>   Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 1 cannot be smaller than version 4 declared in library [com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1] C:\Users\Nitesh\Downloads\SunCalculator (1)\SunCalculator\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\multidex\1.0.1\AndroidManifest.xml
>       Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.multidex" to force usage**

my `build.gradle(Project)` file consists of

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all 

sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

build.gradle(app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "swindroid.suntime"
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` in your `defaultConfig`:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "swindroid.suntime"
    minSdkVersion 25
    targetSdkVersion 25
    multiDexEnabled = true
}
```